# Force Hyper-V to use UTC for RTC?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

Is it possible to configure Hyper-V to present the Real Time Clock (RTC) to Guest as Universal Time Co-ordinates (UTC / GMT)?

I could probably make this happen by setting the Windows (Host) timezone to UTC, but I may not want to make that change because it would affect other things. Really, I just want to change it for a single Guest, or, if necessary, all Guests.

Update: if I configure the guest to tell it the RTC is *local* this leads to other problems because the guest is semi- mobile, so the hyper-v would have to tell the guest the RTC time zone somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the RTC is never local, you know - it is always the interpretation of the guest operating system that gives it a timezone.

Comment: So you are saying my only option is to configure the guest to indicate RTC is local? But what if this guest moves around? How can it know the time zone?

Comment: No, i am saying that the world clock - which hardware runs on - is always UTC and the interpretation is of a given guest. Hardware is always running in UTC.